# Why wont 'justify-content: space-between' make the navbar go to the right hand side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm quite new to html and css but can't seem to wrap my head around why `justify-content` isn't working right. Inline block seems to make sure the `.navbar_wrapper` doesn't have a 100% width and the `<a>` link element doesn't have a `max-width` either so I'm unsure as to why they aren't being spaced at all or affected by the header flex container.

```css
@import url('https"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
}

.logo {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 70px;
}

.navbar_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 94px;
  margin: 0px 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar_wrapper>a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar_wrapper>a:nth-child(4) {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sb_logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
}

.navbar_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="sb_logo" />
      </a>
      <div class="navbar_wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="what's new">What's New</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the HTML you're using `header` and `section` **elements**. But you're targeting those elements in your CSS with `.header` and `.section` **classes**. They're not connecting. Start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the left and right margins from `.logo` and `.navbar_wrapper` will lead to the desired result - see snippet below.

But please note that my fix actually has nothing to do with any flexbox settings. Your flexbox container (`section`) only has one child (`<header>`) -  a situation where flex would be only useful for centering that child (which is not the case here), but nothing else.

My removing the side margins simply moves the `.navbar_wrapper` to the far right (according to its `right: 0;` setting as an absolutely positioned element) and moves the `.logo` element (which does not have a `position` setting) to the left. As I said - has nothing to do with flexbox settings, rather with the absolute position of `.navbar_wrapper`.

But back to your flexbos settings: The `justify-content: space-between;` setting of `section` could be moved to `<header>` to actually be effective. In this case you wouldn't need the absolute position on `.navbar_wrapper` (which IMO would be a better solution).

```css
@import url('https"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
}

.logo {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 94px;
   margin-top: 20px;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar_wrapper>a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar_wrapper>a:nth-child(4) {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sb_logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
}

.navbar_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="sb_logo" />
      </a>
      <div class="navbar_wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="what's new">What's New</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Class `.header` here is not. This is `<header>` tag.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov ??? I just took the snippet from the question and changed  the margin settings on two elements. That has nothing to do with `<header>` or `.header`

Comment: Makes sense thanks. Why is it a better solution to not use flexbox? Or did you mean using flexbox is the better solution?

Comment: Yes, I meant that *not* using the absolute position on `.navbar_wrapper` (but using flexbox on its parent element) is the better solution, since absolute position takes an element out of the document flow, which should only be done in certain situations, but not as a workaround for proper positioning that can be achieved with other methods.